# How to solve the problem that program works in the same way in case of negative numbers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

> As a result, the program must display the 3 largest elements of the sequence. Elements must be displayed from small to large and not using array...
>
> #### Examples
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 3 1 2 3
> ```
>
> Work result:
>
> ```
> 1 2 3
> ```
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 5 2 -4 16 0 15
> ```
>
> Work result:
>
> ```
> 2 15 16
> ```
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 3 0 -1 -2
> ```
>
> Work result:
>
> ```
> -2 -1 0
> ```

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  int number;
  std::cin >> number;
  int max1, max2, max3;
  max1 = max2 = max3 = number;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> number;
    if (number > max3) {
      if (number > max2) {
        if (number > max1) {
          max3 = max2;
          max2 = max1;
          max1 = number;
        } else {
          max2 = number;
        }
      } else {
        max3 = number;
      }
    }
  }
  std::cout << max3 << " " << max2 << " " << max1;
}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` and `std::sort` here? Also what would be different about negative numbers?

Comment: What is the code intended to do? What result do you get with negative numbers vs. what you expect?

Comment: See [mre] ... please add expected result for each input.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My five cents.:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 0;
    int max1, max2, max3;

    std::cin >> n;

    size_t i = 0;
    for ( int number; n-- && std::cin >> number;  i = i < 3 ? i + 1 : i  )
    {
        if ( i == 0 )
        {
            max3 = number;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( max3 < number )
            {
                std::swap( max3, number );
            }

            if ( i == 1 )
            {
                max2 = number;
            }
            else
            {
                if ( max2 < number )
                {
                    std::swap( max2, number );
                }

                if ( i == 2 || max1 < number )
                {
                    max1 = number;
                }       
            }
        }           
    }

    if ( i > 0 )
    {
        std::cout << max3;
    }
    if ( i > 1 )
    {
        std::cout << ", " << max2;
    }
    if ( i > 2 )
    {
        std::cout << ", " << max1;
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
6
5 2 -4 16 0 15
```

then the output is

```
16, 15, 5
```

If to enter

```
6
-5 -2 4 -16 0 -15
```

then the output is

```
4, 0, -2
```

Or if to enter

```
4
3 0 -1 -2
```

then the program output is

```
3, 0, -1
```

Pay attention to that in general the user can enter less than 3 numbers.:)

The solution above allows duplicated maximum values.

If it is required that maximum values shall not be repeated then the program can look the following way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 0;
    int max1, max2, max3;

    std::cin >> n;

    size_t i = 0;
    for ( int number; n-- && std::cin >> number;  )
    {
        if ( i == 0 )
        {
            max3 = number;
            i = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( max3 < number )
            {
                std::swap( max3, number );
            }

            if ( number < max3 )
            {
                if ( i == 1 )
                {
                    max2 = number;
                    i = 2;
                }                   
                else
                {
                    if ( max2 < number )
                    {
                        std::swap( max2, number );
                    }

                    if ( number < max2 )
                    {
                        if ( i == 2 || max1 < number )
                        {
                            max1 = number;
                            i = 3;
                        }       
                    }
                }
            }               
        }           
    }

    if ( i > 0 )
    {
        std::cout << max3;
    }
    if ( i > 1 )
    {
        std::cout << ", " << max2;
    }
    if ( i > 2 )
    {
        std::cout << ", " << max1;
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

For example if to enter

```
5
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

where all numbers are equal each other then the output will contaoin onky one maximum number

```
-1
```

If to use standard containers then the standard container `std::set` is the most appropriate container.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 0;

    std::set<int> set;

    std::cin >> n;

    std::copy_n( std::istream_iterator<int>( std::cin ), n, 
                 std::inserter( set, std::end( set ) ) );

    size_t i = 3;

    for ( auto it = std::rbegin( set ); i-- != 0 && it != std::rend( set ); ++it )
    {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
6
5 2 -4 16 0 15
```

then the output is

```
16 15 5
```

Comment: Vlad from Moscow  thank you very much! 
Your first option was what I needed

Answer (score 1):

I'd use standard algorithms to keep it as simple as possible.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> tests{
        {5, 2, -4, 16, 0, 15},
        {3, 0, -1, -2}
    };
    for(auto& test : tests) {
        // sort the vector to get the three largest last
        std::sort(test.begin(), test.end());

        // create an iterator 3 steps back from the end
        // (or less if the vector doesn't have 3 elements)
        auto first = std::prev(test.cend(), std::min(test.size(), static_cast<size_t>(3)));

        // copy to std::cout
        std::copy(first, test.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5 15 16 
-1 0 3
```

---

A slightly more complicated way involves partially sorting the vector. This makes it more effective since you only need 3 elements sorted.

`std::partial_sort` puts the smallest elements first so we need to sort it in decending order (using `std::greater<>`).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> tests{
        {5, 2, -4, 16, 0, 15},
        {3, 0, -1, -2}
    };
    for(auto& test : tests) {
        // calculate how many elements to show, 0-3
        auto elems = std::min(test.size(), static_cast<size_t>(3)); 

        // sort "elems" elements in decending order
        std::partial_sort(
            test.begin(),
            std::next(test.begin(), elems),
            test.end(),
            std::greater<>()
        );

        // copy the result to std::out, in reverse order since they are sorted "backwards"
        std::copy(
            std::prev(test.crend(), elems),
            test.crend(),
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")
        );
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `std::partial_sort` so you don't have to sort the entire thing.

Comment: @BessieTheCow I agree. That would be more efficient - but I didn't want to complicate it. I added it as an option now though.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main () {
           int n;
           std::cin >> n;
           int number;
           std::cin >> number;
           int max1, max2, max3;
           max1 = max2 = max3 =number;
           for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
           std::cin >> number;
           if (number > max3) {
           if (number > max2) {
           if (number > max1) {
               max3 = max2; 
               max2 = max1;
               max1 = number;
               } else {
               max3 = max2;
               max2 = number;
               }
               } else {
               max3 = number;
               }
               }
               }
               std::cout << max3 << " " << max2 << " " << max1;  
               }
```

If the number is greater than max2 but smaller than max1 then max2 is the new max3 and max2 is number, that was the mistake.

Comment: That's one mistake. There are more.

Comment: when we input numbers  --> 3 0 -1 -2  
the program gives: 0 0 0   
but must give: -2 -1 0

Comment: Yes, because the max values all start at the first number - 0. All negative values are less than that.

Comment: I need the program return -2 -1 0 
how do that???

Answer (score 0):

Do not write everything in `main`. Slice code to smaller pieces to make it easy to read.

Here is an example (a bit to fancy):

```cpp
class AccumulateTopThree
{
public:
    void update(int x)
    {
        if (!isUnique(x)) return;
        keepInOrder(c, x);
        keepInOrder(b, c);
        keepInOrder(a, b);
    }

    void print(std::ostream& out)
    {
        // TODO: handle case when count of input nubers is less then 3
        out << c << ' ' << b << ' ' << a << '\n';
    }

private:
    bool isUnique(int x) const
    {
        return a != x && b != x && c != x;
    }

    static void keepInOrder(int &a, int &b)
    {
        if (a < b) std::swap(a, b);
    }

private:
    int a = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int b = a;
    int c = a;
};
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/OFkQUaGI9PygAV6D

Comment: I need to solve the problem in a simple way...  for example everything write in `main` @Marek R

Comment: everything in `main` is not simpler way.

Comment: I'm just learning C++ so that's why i need a simple solutions ))

Comment: Just to be clear, I did this a bit more fancy then you need on purpose. This way I avoid giving complete solution. If you give some effort you can strip `class` and have a nice code.